# How to add Major compiler framework

Tags: testing

I am trying to automatically generate some mutation for a java program using Major through Mac terminal. And in Major's document, it states installation is just to unzip the folder. However, my terminal seems not to recognize the Major commends, in other words, it is not using the Major compiler. Has anyone encountered a similar situation? What should I do to use its compiler?

http://mutation-testing.org/doc/major.pdf

---

#### Solved

Solution by adding it to the executable path in terminal:

```
export PATH="/Users/username/Desktop/major-1.1.7_jre7/major/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Try adding major's bin folder to your path? To verify if this is the problem navigate to the bin folder inside the downloaded source and then try running javac -version

Comment: Thank you, can you please tell me how to add the bin to my path? I tried javac -version, but it only shows javac's version, but the major-javac's version. is it PATH=/home/cmpt473/Desktop/major/bin:$PATH.

Comment: I figured it out: export PATH="/Users/username/Desktop/major-1.1.7_jre7/major/bin:$PATH"